# IRC feedparser index out of range mysterious error

Tags: python, exception, rss, bots

I am trying to code rss news feeder bot for irc. So I search a bit on web a little and made out this code

```
#this code is for local testing
import feedparser
feed_list = {}
channel = '#hackingdefined'

class Feed:
    def __init__(self, name, url):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.feeds = {}
        self.newest = ''

    def update(self):
        self.feeds = feedparser.parse(self.url)
        if self.newest != self.feeds['items'][0].title:
            self.newest = self.feeds['items'][0].title
            say('{}: {} '.format(self.name,self.newest))
            say('URL: {} '.format(self.feeds.entries[0].link))

def say(data=''):
    print('PRIVMSG '+channel+' :'+ data+'\r\n')

def url_loader(txt):
    f = open(txt, 'r')
    for line in f:
        name, url = line.split(':',1) # check how to spilt only once
        print name+" "+url
        feed_list[name] = Feed(name,url)
    print feed_list

url_loader('feed_list.txt')
for feed in feed_list.values():
    print feed
    feed.update()
```

When I run the code I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Or\define\projects\rss feed\the progect\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    feed.update()
  File "C:\Or\define\projects\rss feed\the progect\test.py", line 14, in update
    if self.newest != self.feeds['items'][0].title:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Now the wierd thing is, if I create a new Feed class like `test = Feed('example', 'http://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/')`
and call `test.update()` Its all work fine, but the automation script raise an error.

So i checked my url_load and the test file,The test file is something like this:

```
packet storm:http://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/
sans:http://www.sans.org/rss.php/
...
```

And its all seems fine to me.  Any one have a clue what this could be?

Thanks, Or

EDIT:

Its been solved, one of my url was wrong.
All seem clear after good night sleep :-)

Comment: I solve it, add try on the feed/update and discover that one of the url is wrong...

Comment: You should now post the solution as an answer and then accept it. It will show everyone that the issue closed and also it will keep the solution clearly visible for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been solved, one of my url that i post into the file was wrong.
The solution is use try on every url in the list.